# Network Connection Error ios 8.3 sim

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

I'm building an app and using alamofire to make web requests. When I attempt to make a request in iOS simulator 8.3 (any model) I get an NSURLErrorDomain code=-1005. YET, safari inside the simulator works just fine. My code and requests also work fine in all iOS 7.1 simulators. This is getting beyond frustrating for me to solve since restarting the simulator, resetting the content and settings and restarting xcode + computer has not solved the issue. Any ideas?